# Is it possible to setup HP DV2000 model laptop to be as a WiFi hotspot to my smartphone(not another computer)?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have seen [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GI-s5x4lLLw&feature=player_embedded) and did exactly like that but I am not able to do this. Also I am not able to find the wifi bios setting mentioned in the video.

Please help

OS: Win XP

Comment: I think it is completelly possible, did you already try?

Comment: Yes but it disables one network if another is enabled.. as mentioned in the video but couldnt find bios setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 provides a function called HostedNetwork, documented at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which allows your computer to simultaneously connect to a wireless network and broadcast your own secondary network. To use this feature, you must have a compatible wireless card.

To configure the network, in an elevated command prompt type:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork SSID=<ssid> key=<key> keyUsage=persistent
```

after which you can start it with `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` and stop it with `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork`. Currently there is no way of running an unsecured hosted network.

Once you set up the hostednetwork, you can use it to share your existing wireless network.

However, if you intend to share a *wired* internet connection, you do not need to set up hostednetwork. To share a wired network, right click on the "Local Area Connection" entry in "Network Connections" (Control Panel), and select the "Advanced" tab, and check "Allow other ...". A detailed guide on how to set up Internet Connection Sharing under Windows XP can be found at the [Microsoft Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126)

Answer (score 0):

Missing some information here that would probably help someone to provide a solution - what operating system is installed on the laptop?

Comment: added the info..